how to write |.| symbol for distance in latex?
I want to write this symbol in latex |.|, which dot is in the middle of lines but I dont remember how it is called.
DO you know how can I do it?

Btw I found out you can do /Vert which is basically just 2 lines ||

I usually do
\newcommand{\blank}{{\cdot}}

and input something like you want as
\lvert\blank\rvert

Example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\blank}{{\cdot}}

\begin{document}

$\lvert\blank\rvert$

$f(\blank)$

$\hom(X,\blank)$

\end{document}


Why defining \blank and not using {\cdot} directly? The idea is not to be tied to a particular representation. Indeed, doing so makes us free to change the definition. For instance, we may want to add some horizontal space around the centered dot. With
\newcommand{\blank}{{\mspace{2mu}\cdot\mspace{2mu}}}

we'd get

Or maybe you want to do like it's frequently done in category theory. Then
\newcommand{\blank}{{-}}

would produce


thank you, just the answer I was searching: $\lvert\blank\rvert$

Just in addition to egregs answer, here's something that generates a simpler syntax
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\abs[1]\lvert\rvert
{ \IfBlankTF{#1}{{\cdot}}{#1} }
\begin{document}
\[ \abs{x} \]
\[ \abs{}  \]
\end{document}

Additionally \abs*{A} is the same as \left\lvert A \right\rvert and \abs[\Big]{A} is the same as \Bigl\lvert A \Bigr\rvert
The macro \IfBlankTF probably need a newer LaTeX installation.

As an aside, using \lvert…\rvert in place of |…| is only necessary if what’s inside the absolute sign begins with a binary operator (e.g., \lvert -3 \rvert = 3. Otherwise, the spacing is identical.

@DonHosek it is always better to use a construction that works in all cases

Using mismath package.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mismath}
\begin{document}
$\abs{\cdot}, d(u,v)=\abs{u-v}$
\end{document}


